# User cannot view site collection admin settings eventhough user is already assigned as admin

Tags: permissions, site-collection

I want to assign this user as site collection admin.

I have added the user in the site collection admin list, added in owner groups (giving him full control), I have also added him in the User Policy list in the CA and added his name as secondary site collection admin but still he is not able to see the site collection admin settings!

I did testing by adding another user in the User Policy list and he can instantly see changes in the site settings.

Any clue on why this happens?

FYI: The site is using FBA to login

Comment: It turns out I just needed to add the user using Forms Authentication account, not AD account. Thanks for your input anyway Benny :)

Comment: Just to add, to add the user using their FBA account, I need to type in the full FBA login name of the user, then only the FBA username will appear under suggestions in the input box

Answer (score 2):

It should work, but sometimes SharePoint cache user permission in the user information list. Often recently added phone numbers or e-mail addresses doesn't show if the user have a record in the user information list. Your case is different, but I've seen it happen before and resolved the same by removing the user from the user information list in the site collection. When done, add the user in the site collection owner group with full permission should be enough.

It's worth a try, so head over to

- http://SiteCollectionURL/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx or
- http://SiteCollectionURL/_catalogs/users/